# RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT not so immediate?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I previously asked a question on how to do a `PRINT` that gives output immediately while the rest of the script is still running (See: [How to see progress of running SQL stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132847/how-to-see-progress-of-running-sql-stored-procedures)). The simple answer is to use:

```
RAISERROR ('My message', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

However, I noticed that the returned output is not always immediate, especially when it returns a lot of results. As a simple experiment, consider the following script:

```
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count = 1

WHILE @count <= 5000
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Message %d', 0, 1, @count) WITH NOWAIT
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.01'
    SET @count = @count + 1
END
```

The above script will spits out 5000 lines of text. If you run the script, you will notice:

- For the first 500 lines (1 - 500 lines), it returns each output line immediately.
- For the next 500 lines (501 - 1000 lines), it returns the output once every 50 lines. (All 50 lines will be batched together and returned only at the end of each 50th line.)
- For every line after that (1001 - * lines), it returns the output once every 100 lines. (All 100 lines will be batched together and returned only at the end of each 100th line.)

So that means after the first 500 lines, the `RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT` no longer work as expected, and cause problems to me because I want to see the progress of my very long running script.

So my question: Is there any way to disable this 'batched' behaviour and make it always return immediately?

---

**EDIT:** I'm using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to run the above script . It seems to affect all versions (both SSMS and SQL Server), and whether the output is set to "Results to Text" or "Results to Grid" makes no difference.

**EDIT:** Apparently, this batched behaviour happens after 500 lines, *regardless* of the number of bytes. So, I've updated the question above accordingly.

**EDIT:** Thanks to **Fredou** for pointing out that this is an issue with SSMS and third party tools like *LinqPad* will not have this issue.

However, I found out that *LinqPad* doesn't output immediately either when you have table results in the output. For example, consider the following code:

```
RAISERROR ('You should see this immediately', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases
RAISERROR ('You should see this immediately too, along with a table above.', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
RAISERROR ('You should see this 5 seconds later...', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

When you run the above script in LinqPad, only the first line is output immediately. The rest will only output after 5 seconds...

So, anyone know of a good light-weight alternative to SSMS that is free, does not require installation and will work with immediate outputs of RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT mixed with table results?

Comment: I doubt its a batching issue, it would seem to me that its just when the processor gets the thread to spit to the window and what you're seeing is just latency on the machine.

Comment: Then why the 3 different sets of behaviour? And they are very consistent too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Query ExPlus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/queryexplus/?source=pdlp) seems to do the trick, as long as you **set the output option to "Results In Text"**.

Another crude alternative is `sqlcmd`, which is installed as part of SQL Server. That works as well, but table results tend to be jumbled up and hard to read on the command console screen...

Comment: Sqlcmd does not work as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107499/how-to-make-raiserror-with-nowait-work-with-sqlcmd?noredirect=1#comment63649041_38107499

Comment: Yes, Query ExPlus is very useful for running all kinds of queries. Your Volkswagen is perfectly fine for going to the corner shop for a few groceries, and you don't need to fire up the space shuttle.

Comment: One limitation of Query ExPlus worth mentioning is that it struggles when printing tens or hundreds of thousands of lines of text output (whether with `PRINT` or `RAISERROR`). But it does seem to display the output of `RAISERROR...WITH NOWAIT` *immediately*, unlike SQL Server Management Studio, which seems to wait for batches of 100 lines of text if there's a lot of output.

Answer (score 10):

It would appear this works in 2008R2 if you set results to text.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

it seem it is a limitation of sql server management studio >= 2005

if you have 2000, you would not have this limitation

[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6438e267-b7a4-4961-b893-14a5980dfb0e/print-within-while-loop-is-not-being-displayed?forum=transactsql)

i have just tried your code with LinqPad and i cannot reproduce this behavior

Comment: @SFLee, i think i found a way to get what you want, if you are ready to use something else than management studio

Comment: You mean using LinqPad? Does it support running SQL scripts? (Converting it to C# LINQ is not an option, as it's a very large script.)

Comment: @SFLee, you can run pure sql script, just select that option in the dropdown list. this i was i did

Comment: @SFLee, if you look at the screenshot on the homepage of linqpad, first dropdown with the text c# expression. you can select SQL instead. which now will accept pure sql code

Comment: @SFLee, there is a standalone zip file available that do not required an installation

Comment: Found some problems with LinqPad... See the EDIT section in my main question above.