# Problems with Oracle long-lived connection in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, goracle

I am trying to deploy a Go application inside the Kubernetes cluster. My application uses the `goracle.v2` library to connect to the Oracle database.

The problem only happens when my application is running inside the Kubernetes cluster. I have a process that executes a stored procedure and returns a cursor, and it often takes more than 10 minutes to execute.

When this happens the active session that was there in the database ends and the pod that was running with the application is stopped and nothing else happens. And this scenario only happens when it runs inside the cluster. If I run the app locally it doesn't happen even if the process takes more than 10 minutes.

Anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: It could be a network related [issue](https://tech.xing.com/a-reason-for-unexplained-connection-timeouts-on-kubernetes-docker-abd041cf7e02)
From another point of view you should try to to watch the progress of your query/task - once finished your script should finished as completed [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132847/how-to-see-progress-of-running-sql-stored-procedures)

Comment: At a guess, try setting the SQL*Net option EXPIRE_TIME.  If your Oracle client libraries are 18+, you can set this in a "client" sqlnet.ora file where you deploy your app.  With a 19c client you could even add it to the connection string, see the last paragraph in https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-1421-easy-connect-syntax-for-connection-strings which is also valid for goracle.  If you have older clients, you will need to set this in the database sqlnet.ora, or use the even older ENABLE=BROKEN option